# How many languages will the official GUI support?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, language

How many languages will the official GUI support at launch?

Were the translations done with help from native speakers or by Transifex?

Comment: Also see [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4mfe56/can_we_use_this_to_make_translations_more/d3vk78w?ref=search_posts)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[7 mnemonic seed languages](https://github.com/mbg033/monero-core/commit/a9339838ac295a4d045433c1b20fd5666fb35575#diff-fa69490cceb5160ef2d4d0a3d1a42981L2) will be available for the GUI:

```
  +List of available languages for your wallet's seed:
    +0 : English
    +1 : Spanish
    +2 : German
    +3 : Italian
    +4 : Portuguese
    +5 : Russian
    +6 : Japanese
```

11 wallet "locales" are supported with [5 different languages](https://github.com/mbg033/monero-core/commit/a9339838ac295a4d045433c1b20fd5666fb35575#diff-fa69490cceb5160ef2d4d0a3d1a42981R14):

```
+        <language display_name="US English" locale="en_US" wallet_language="English" flag="/lang/flags/usa.png" qs="none"/>
+        <language display_name="UK English" locale="en_GB" wallet_language="English" flag="/lang/flags/uk.png" qs="none"/>
+        <language display_name="Russia"     locale="ru_RU" wallet_language="Russian" flag="/lang/flags/russia.png" qs="none"/>
+        <language display_name="RPA"        locale="en_SA" wallet_language="English" flag="/lang/flags/rpa.png" qs="none"/>
+        <language display_name="Palestine"  locale="ar_PS" wallet_language="English" flag="/lang/flags/palestine.png" qs="none"/>
+        <language display_name="India"      locale="hi_IN" wallet_language="English" flag="/lang/flags/india.png" qs="none"/>
+        <language display_name="Italy"      locale="it_IT" wallet_language="Italian" flag="/lang/flags/italy.png" qs="none"/>
+        <language display_name="German"     locale="de_DE" wallet_language="German"  flag="/lang/flags/german.png" qs="none"/>
+        <language display_name="China"      locale="zh_CN" wallet_language="English" flag="/lang/flags/china.png" qs="none"/>
+        <language display_name="Brazil"     locale="pt_BR" wallet_language="Portuguese" flag="/lang/flags/brazil.png" qs="none"/>
+        <language display_name="Bangladesh" locale="en_US" wallet_language="English" flag="/lang/flags/bangladesh.png" qs="none"/>
```

Translations will be automatic with the support of [QML](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_do_dynamic_translation_in_QML) which relies on the internationalization capabilities provided by Qt on which the new Monero GUI is being built.

Comment: That's 7 languages in the first list not 6.